# How does Nilbogism interact with features that have a random table of effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The Nilbog at page 182 in Volo's Guide to Monsters has the following feature:

> **Nilbogism.** Any creature that attempts to damage the nilbog must first succeed on a DC 12 Charisma saving throw or be charmed until the end of the creature's next turn. A creature charmed in this way must use its action praising the nilbog. The nilbog can't regain hit points, including through magical healing, except through its Reversal of Fortune reaction.

So if anyone would use the a [Wand of Wonder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-wonder), even the nilbog himself, would they have to make a Charisma Save before using it if there is a slim chance they could harm the nilbog?

If the nilbog would use it, there are a lot which could happen to him:
stunned on a 11-15, potential 1d6 psychic damage on a 21-25, potentially standing in a fireball 70-79, blinded on a 91-95, petrified on a 98-00.

Comment: Please, try to ask one question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The verb is "attempts to damage".

To "attempt" is to act with intent. Nobody zaps a wand at a creature for no reason. If you're using the Wand of Wonder with the intent to damage the nilbog, you have to make the save. Given that several of the possible effects are damaging, if you are an enemy of the nilbog, your intent presumably is to damage it. (Or else you don't know what the wand does; this shouldn't typically happen with the Wand of Wonder because it requires attunement.)

On the other hand, if the nilbog activates the wand, it's probably not trying to damage itself, even if that is a possible outcome.